# How can i get latitude and longitude by giving address manually in mapquest?

Tags: javascript, mapquest

This is the code I have.  I want to implement the manual functionality and here we gave the location in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    L.mapquest.key = 'key';

    var popup = L.popup();

    var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
      center: [38.890385, -77.031989],
      layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
      zoom: 14
    });

    map.addControl(L.mapquest.control());

    map.on('click', function(e) {
      popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(this);
      L.mapquest.geocoding().reverse(e.latlng, generatePopupContent);
    });

    function generatePopupContent(error, response) {
      var location = response.results[0].locations[0];
      var street = location.street;
      var city = location.adminArea5;
      var state = location.adminArea3;
      popup.setContent(street + ', ' + city + ', ' + state);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That code does a reverse geocoding, which is the process of obtaining a street address given some coordinates. What you need to use is simple geocoding, which will provide you coordinates from a street address.

You can find the documentation about MapQuest geocoding [here](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.1/examples/basic-geocoding/).

Obviously, you'll need to do all the rest, such as obtaining the address from a form or something like that.

Comment: You can also use the search ahead function when accepting input from the map user and geocode the chosen result. A sample can be found here. https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.1/examples/geocoding-control-with-search-ahead/